# apache config - vhost item listed but cannot be found

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, with Apache installed by `tasksel`.

`apache2ctl -S` says `www.ijiameng.com` exist in different conf files, in which default has higher priority, as below:

```
sunjizu@HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$ apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.ijiameng.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.ijiameng.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost foo.my (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.my.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.ijiameng.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ijiameng.net.conf:1)
                 alias ijiameng.net
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
```

but `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` does not include anything related to `www.ijiameng.com`, as belows:

```
sunjizu@HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ cat 000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet 
</VirtualHost>
```

The result is very annoying, that is, when I browse `http://www.ijameng.net`, the browser goes straight to `/var/www/`, which is default config.
But `ijiameng.net` works well, because there's no conflicting config.

Anything is hidden in `000-default.conf`?

Comment: try to run /etc/init.d/apache2 stop and /etc/init.d/apache2 start to see if  you have some setting lingering

Comment: I've tried ```sudo service apache2 restart``` many times, but doesn't work :<

Comment: It seems that apache registers the server's hostname (as defined in `/etc/hostname` and/or `/etc/hosts`) as default site. possible workarounds are changing the server's hostname, setting a `ServerName` in the default vhost or disabling the default vhost altogether. These workarounds may have some side effects, though.

Comment: You could always disable the default server if it is useless. That might work.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I just ```sudo a2dissite 000-default```, and default rules go with the wind, whew...

Answer (score 2):

The Default configuration starting with `000` is listed in a higher order because it is the first to be included, as the enabled sites will be read in numerical order followed by alphabetical order.
This can be overwritten by specifying the multiple Include entries to control the order:

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ijiameng.net.conf
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.my.conf
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Presumably the reason that `www.ijiameng.net` is showing in the default config is because it shares the IP address with your host.

Please post the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ijiameng.net.conf` config as if the default conf is being picked up instead of vhost conf then chances are the problem is with the vhost entry.